# Batch script to process multiple .txt files processes only one

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that should process multiple input files, and create a separate output file for each. However, my issues are:

1. It reads only the first text file
2. It goes into an infinite loop after creating the first output file.

I need the script to make a **separate output** file for **each input** file. How can I achieve this?

The code is currently as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=0
for /r %%x in (*.txt) do (                     //SUPPOSED to read all input files
for /f "tokens=4 delims=|" %%a in (%%x) do (... goto: GETLINE))

:GETLINE
if not %line%==0 set skip=skip=%line%
for %%x in (*.txt) do ( ...
echo %%b >>"Output_%%x.txt"                           //writing into output
goto :BREAK
))
:BREAK
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in the `:GETLINE` function.

If that is called you are looping over all files again, and reading each line again.

Try using this instead

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=0
for /r %%x in (*.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=4 delims=|" %%a in (%%x) do (
set num=%%a
set num=!num: =!
if !num!==589 set bool=true
if !num!==581 set bool=true
if !num!==580 set bool=true
if !num!==027 set bool=true
if !num!==582 set bool=true
if !num!==585 set bool=true
if "!bool!"=="true" call :GETLINE "%%x"
set /a line+=1
set bool=false
)
)

:GETLINE
if not %line%==0 set skip=skip=%line%
for /f "usebackq %skip% tokens=* delims=" %%b in ("%~1") do (
echo %%b >>"Output_%%x.txt"
goto :BREAK
)
)
:BREAK
```

Which will call `:GETLINE` and pass it the current file in the loop, which will stop it from looping everything again.

Comment: That didn't work Bali.. Directory is incorrect or something. Tried `set file_list=C:\BatchScripting\*.txt
for %%x in (%file_list%) do (` but then no output there.

Comment: Ah, I removed the other `for` loop in my answer, which breaks the output line as `%%x` doesn't exist anymore, trying changing it to `echo %%b >>"Output_%1`.txt"` instead.